# How to create declaration file for react-typist or another package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

How to create typescript declaration for npm package that don't have a @types package.

I want to use npm package `react-typist`, but because there are no package `@types/react-typist`, then I need write own declaration.

I tried samething but it's not worked.

https://github.com/yelidric/filipmady.com

But react still show me declaration error.

I dont know what to do. Can u tell me what I do wrong or get me same links for good resources for beginners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a directory called `@types`, I put mine in `PROJECT_ROOT/src`:

```
src ->
  @types
```

Then in types make a folder called `react-typist`, and inside of that folder make a file named `index.d.ts`.

```
src ->
  @types ->
    react-typist ->
      index.d.ts
```

Inside of `index.d.ts` just add this single line:

```
declare module 'react-typist'
```

Now the module and its exports will all be assigned the `any` type